# C#, the code is compiling but the search function does not work

Tags: c#, if-statement, search

this a simple part of my code that does not work whatever I do. And I have already asked a lot of people regarding this, so this is my last hope i guess. The only problem that I have lies in case 3 when the user can search for an older post. What happens is that the program just returns the else statement everytime. To make it easer for you to understand, I will past all code:
ps. The search has to be linear

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Loggbok
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime tiden = DateTime.UtcNow;//Skriver ut tiden vid varje inlägg
            bool running = true;//Ger ett booleskt värde till variabeln running för att kunna skapa en loop
            List<string[]> loggbok = new List<string[]>();//Här skapas listan som innehåller arrayen

            while (running)//Här skapas loopen
            {
            Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("\nVälkommen till loggboken!");
            Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("\n[1] Skriv nytt inlägg i loggboken");
            Console.WriteLine("[2] Skriv ut alla loggar");
            Console.WriteLine("[3] Sök inlägg i loggboken");
            Console.WriteLine("[4] Radera innehåll i loggboken");
            Console.WriteLine("[5] Avsluta loggboken");
            Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
            Console.Write("\nVälj: ");

            int option;//Int eftersom valet ska vara ett heltal
            string[] logg = new string[2];//Här deklareras arrayen

            try
            {
                option = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//testar så att inmatningen är av typen Int

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fel, du får bara skriva in nummer");//Felmeddelande om inmatningen är en bokstav
                continue;
            }

            switch (option)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
                    Console.WriteLine(tiden);
                    Console.WriteLine("Ange en Titel:");
                    logg[0] = Console.ReadLine();//Här sparas titeln
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
                    Console.WriteLine("Skriv inlägg:");
                    logg[1] = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Console.ReadLine(), Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));//Här sparas inlägget samt datum och tid, detta är möjligt tack vare formattering 
                    loggbok.Add(logg);
                    break;


                case 2:
                    foreach (string[] item in loggbok)//För att skriva ut alla items i loggboken
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------\n ");
                        Console.WriteLine(item[0]);//För att skriva ut titel
                        Console.WriteLine(item[1]);//För att skriva ut inlägg
                        Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------------------\n ");
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    break;





                case 3:

                    Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
                    Console.WriteLine("Skriv in ett ord du vill söka efter i loggboken:");
                    string nyckelord = Console.ReadLine();//Här sparas inmatningen av nyckelordet

                    for (int i = 0; i < logg.Length; i++)
                    {

                        if (logg[i] == nyckelord)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(logg[i]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("finns inte");
                        }

                    }





                        break;






                case 4:

                    Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
                    Console.WriteLine("Skriv titeln på det inlägg du vill ta bort:");
                    string title = Console.ReadLine();//Sparar titeln på inlägget användaren vill radera

                    for (int x = 0; x < loggbok.Count; x++) //Loopa igenom varje titel
                    {
                        if (String.Equals(loggbok[x][0], title, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) //Icke skiftlägeskänslig matchning av titeln.
                        {
                            loggbok.RemoveAt(x); //Matchning funnen.
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Titeln finns inte, återgår till huvudmenyn");
                        }


                    }
                    break; //Avsluta loopen.


                case 5:

                    running = false;//Avslutar loopen och därmed programmet
                    break;


                default:

                    Console.WriteLine("Nu blev det fel, välj mellan [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]");//Felmeddelande om valet är någon annan siffra än de som menyn innehåller
                    break;









            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how do you know it's _always_ going into the else block when all you do is print the same thing both within the _if_ and _else_ block which is this -->  `Console.WriteLine(logg[i]);`

Comment: Since your `if` and `else` blocks do the same thing, you can just remove the conditional entirely and just do that one thing.

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to do - writing `logg[i]` in both cases. Why would you expect the outcome to be different?

Comment: I did that just to try if it would work that way, it didn't. So the problem lies in variabel somewhere. So my conclusion is that there is something wrong with the variable and not the if else statement.

Comment: You are searching in ```logg``` instead of ```loggbok```.

Comment: I will edit my post and you can see what I mean

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh Thanks. But how do i change this. I have changed logg to loggbok, but there is still some formatting to be done, and I don't know have? How would you change this from logg to loggbok in a syntax point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It will search your requested string both in title and message.

```
case 3:
    Console.WriteLine("\n************************************");
    Console.WriteLine("Skriv in ett ord du vill söka efter i loggboken:");
    string nyckelord = Console.ReadLine();//Här sparas inmatningen av nyckelordet

    bool found = false;
    foreach (string[] item in loggbok)
    {
        if (item.Any(l => l.Contains(nyckelord)))
        {
            found = true;
            Console.WriteLine(item[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(item[1]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("finns inte");
    }

    break;
```

And please use English in text constants and comments, it will help to understand your code.

Also it will be better to create class or structure to store your post data (title and message) instead of using `string[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking in the wrong place. You are searching through `logg` when you probably want to search through `loggbok`.

Comment: Ok thanks, That is the list yes, and every log is in that list. So how do I reach them in my for statement?

Comment: See the answer @uladzimir-palekh provided, his is more direct and comprehensive.